# Can I use wget to run a local file as a cron job using relative path above public_html?

Tags: php, cron, wget

I'm trying to setup a script to run in a cron job, and I want it to run once a day. I'm new to cron jobs, and the ones I have seen so far are only using absolute paths like:

http://example.com/path/to/file.

This is the command I want to do in cpanel:

/usr/bin/wget -O - -q -t 1 /home/account/invest/controllers/cron_controller.php

Would this work? Or is another command better than wget?

Comment: `wget` makes a HTTP request and requires an URL, not a filepath.

Comment: `GNU Wget is a free software package for retrieving files using HTTP, HTTPS and FTP, the most widely-used Internet protocols.` https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/

Comment: Use directly php cli. Usually located at `/usr/bin/php` (is usually a symlink to `/usr/bin/php5` (or to php7 if installed)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best command is `php /home/account/invest/controllers/cron_controller.php`.

Comment: Do I need to add user/bin in front of php?

Comment: You can  run the command `whereis php` to find php's full path, but usually you don't have to. You can simply  use `php`.